# codeigniter session time to update made some session variables unset after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My codeigniter application version is 2.1.4

I'm trying to make session time as large as I can because it was log users out a lot so I changed the config as you see.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';    
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1209600;// two weeks    
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;    
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;    
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;    
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';    
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;    
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;    
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 1209500;
```

after this it didn't log me out from yesterday till now but some session variables unset after redirecting

my last change in config before find out this problem was changing session time to update from 100 sec to 1209500

Do you know how to fix it without changing session time to update?

Comment: I do not think it will be good for session to stay for 2 weeks.

Comment: I think that too, but it was my way now to stop logging user out in a really bad timing

Comment: At what point does it log you out? After some controller function? A simple redirect?

Comment: After some functions
I think any function that check if user is login

Comment: that's not happening all the time but happening a lot